# What operations would cause a validated changeset to become invalidated and lose the Quick Deploy option?

Tags: change-set, quick-deploy

When I validate a changeset it takes 4 - 6 hours to run all tests, then once validated the Quick Deploy option is available. I will schedule the deployment to happen 2 to 3 days after that, as appropriate to reduce user downtime etc.

While waiting for my deployment window there may be requests to make changes, I generally try to hold off on any changes until the deployment is finished but wonder what operations can be safely performed without affecting the Quick Deploy. I don't want to have to run the validation again, if I don't have to.

- Is there a list of operations that can be safely performed?
- Is there a list of operations that will invalidated a Quick Deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is no deployment or package installation in the meantime there shouldn't be any problem.

> If you perform a deployment after a validation, whether through Quick Deploy, a package installation, or a regular deployment, all validations no longer qualify for quick deployment. Revalidate the set of components to quick-deploy.
> (Source: [Monitor Deployments - Quick Deployments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=deploy_monitoring.htm&type=0&language=en_us#quickdeploy_title))

Answer (score 1):

[Markus Slabina](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/36218/markus-slabina) has the correct answer. For peace of mind I also took some time to verify this, sometimes the documentation isn't incorrect :) While not exhaustive I was able to verify that the following operations do not invalidate a Quick Deploy:

- Security Controls

  - Edit Session Settings
  - Edit Password Policies
  - Edit Network Access
  - Edit Named Credentials
- Profiles

  - Edit Object Settings
  - Edit App Permissions
  - Edit Custom Permissions
  - Edit System Permissions
  - Edit Login IP Ranges
  - Edit Password Policies
  - Edit Login Hours
- User

  - Add new User
  - Make inactive User active
- Queues

  - Assign User to Queue
- Groups

  - Assign User to Group
- Edit Case Assignment Rules
- Schedule Apex

  - Schedule an Apex Job
  - Remove Scheduled Apex Job
- Create new Sandbox
- Upload new Changeset